# How to make previous and next items visible using PageView in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, pageviews

How to make the previous and the next items of a PageView visible at the ends of the screen slightly?

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First you need to specify the page controller's viewport fraction which defaults to 1.0 :

```
final _controller = PageController(viewportFraction: 0.7);
```

Then use the custom controller for your page view:

```
PageView.builder(
              itemCount: _pages.length,
              controller: _controller,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return _pages[index];
              },
            )
```

Answer (score 1):

To make next and previous card visible you can try to use in PageView  viewportFraction

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_uuFKMCA1m4

Answer (score -2):

You need to reduce the width of the pages in the page view so you can display more